# Packing in Python and Unpacking in C

Tags: python, c, ctypes, packing

I'm trying to pack integers as bytes in python and unpack them in C. So in my python code I have something like

```
testlib = ctypes.CDLL('/something.so')
testlib.process(repr(pack('B',10)))
```

which packs 10 as a byte and calls the function "process" in my C code.

What do I need in my C code to unpack this packed data? That is, what do I need to do to get 10 back from the given packed data.

Comment: Why the `repr`? That'll add quotes around your bytes, I doubt you want that.

Comment: What does the C function prototype for `process` look like?  Can you change it?  If so, why not just make it take an integer and skip the whole byte packing entirely?

Comment: I can change the C code but the purpose of the code is to unpack something packed in python so skipping the packing entirely is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a 10 byte string containing 10 integers, just copy the data.

```
char packed_data[10];
int unpacked[10];

int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    unpacked[i] = packed_data[i];
```

... or using `memcpy`

On the other hand, if you're using 4 bytes pr int when packing, you can split the char string in C and use `atoi` on it. How are you exchanging data from Python to C ?

Comment: I'm actually doing something like testlib.process(repr(pack('B',8))) where repr(pack('B',8)) is a string '\x08'. Not sure if this is the correct/best way to do it.